# display non-English language text in a message box

Tags: ms-access

i wrote the following code in my application which is in MS Access, to display a message box in Farsi language(non-English language), but while i am typing in Farsi(Persion) it types in some special/unknown/different characters, and also while i run the application the message box displays that special/different characters instead of "احمد" which i want to be display.

msgbox("احمد")

any help well be my pleasure, and i really need for any kind of reply and help pleaseeeee.

Comment: as well as when i change a lable caption to show some Farsi text, it displays unknown characters instead of Farsi(Persion). through this code line: myLabel.Caption="احمد"

Comment: pleasee help i am just stacked....

Answer (score 1):

Might check into *unicode* options for the controls you're using.

**Edit: Based on a bit of googling I did, there doesn't seem to be any unicode support built in to msgbox (surprise to me), but other controls do support it by default apparently, leading to custom solutions.  See below for links.**

A forum post I found mentions a custom msgbox creator:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/msgbox-wont-display-unicode-characters-t2766299.html

Another post discussing how to make forms that will display a unicode message:
http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.access/browse_frm/thread/4f2cd646023e0054/892dfd73309ad76b

Comment: There is no such option for any control

Comment: Wow, sorry for the dud answer. After some searching, I there isn't any unicode functionality in MsgBox. I did find a forum post that mentioned a custom msg box creator that might handle your use case. See my edit.