# Displaying Unicode characters: Excel 2010 vs Excel 2013

Tags: excel, internationalization, excel-2010, vba

I need to substitute plain ASCII for Unicode characters in an Excel spreadsheet. Eg convert Ståle to Stale.

The following works fine in Excel 2013. But in Excel 2010, a "?" is displayed instead of the problematic character. Any ideas? Note that the non-Ascii characters are correctly detected in Excel 2010, but the characters aren't displayed.

```
char = Mid(val, i, 1)
char_code = AscW(char)
If char_code > 127 Then
  MsgBox ("Problem with " & c.Address & " [" & char_code & "] " &
    StrConv(ChrW(char_code), vbUnicode))
End If
```

I also tried just

```
MsgBox ("Problem with " & char & " " & ChrW(char_code))
```

Again it worked with Excel 2013 but not Excel 2010.

Comment: Perhaps as an option this will be ok: http://www.asap-utilities.com/asap-utilities-excel-tools-tip.php?tip=236&utilities=78&lang=en_us

Comment: StrConv relies on the default code page.  I assume you are trying this on different computers.  Does the computer with Excel 2010 have the correct code page?  Would converting char_code to hexadecimal be a better option?

Answer (score 2):

More research reveals:

The MsgBox control for Excel 2010 does not support Unicode characters. The Excel 2013 MsgBox does.

The Unicode non-ASCII character works fine when the character is inserted into a worksheet cell. The problem is only when using MsgBox to display it. Good news is that the problem is fixed in Excel 2013. [More on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013443/display-non-english-language-text-in-a-message-box)